# SQL Server (SSMS) Losing or Not Recognizing Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I've run into an issue a couple times now where I'll encase a query in BEGIN TRAN / ROLLBACK TRAN (so I can verify it works before committing any changes), and will get the error below. The BEGIN TRAN statement does not generate an error.

> The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION

The commands I was using the most recent time are below. I didn't save the errors at the time, but I believe that the UPDATE commands also errored because it didn't recognize ClientId as a valid column.

Each time it has done this, some statements have been rolled back, and others remained. In this case, I have neither a ClientId nor a ClientCode column.

I also can't perfectly recreate the initial run since running these outside of a transaction has caused me to lose all of my ClientCode fields, and the ClientId fields are not in the tables. Thankfully, none of the dev data was important, but because of its volume, it'll take me a little bit to repopulate.

Initially, I thought I'd just selected some of the query before running it, ommiting the BEGIN TRAN, so I reran it, careful to select everything and got the same error, as well as a host of others caused by the missing ClientCode field.

I'd like to know why this is happening so I can prevent it in the future.

EDIT: I did some additional testing on a later date and I have been unable to recreate this behavior. The transactions are being rolled back correctly, and the UPDATE command is not erroring for having an invalid column

```
BEGIN TRAN

ALTER TABLE tblInvoices ADD ClientId INT NULL
GO
UPDATE tblInvoices
SET ClientId = c.Id
FROM tblInvoices i
INNER JOIN Core.dbo.tblClients c
ON i.ClientCode = c.ClientCode
GO
ALTER TABLE tblInvoices ALTER COLUMN ClientId INT NOT NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE tblInvoices DROP COLUMN ClientCode

GO



ALTER TABLE tblClientSettings ADD ClientId INT NULL
GO
UPDATE tblClientSettings
SET ClientId = c.Id
FROM tblClientSettings cs
INNER JOIN Core.dbo.tblClients c
ON cs.ClientCode = c.ClientCode
GO
ALTER TABLE tblClientSettings ALTER COLUMN ClientId INT NOT NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE tblClientSettings DROP COLUMN ClientCode

GO

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

EDIT 2: It happened again on a small set of commands. The commands and the output messages are below.

Input:

```
BEGIN TRAN




CREATE TABLE tblEmailTemplates(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Subject NVARCHAR(2000) NULL,
    Body NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    Sender NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    Recipients NVARCHAR(2000) NULL,
    CC NVARCHAR(2000) NULL,
    BCC NVARCHAR(2000) NULL,
    Html BIT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE tblContactSeries (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    AppId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Foo_Apps.dbo.tblApps(Id),
    Description NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].tblEmails(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SeriesId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES tblContactSeries(Id),
    TemplateId INT NULL REFERENCES tblEmailTemplates(Id),
    TemplateParameters NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Sender] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Recipients] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [CC] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [BCC] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [Subject] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [Body] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Html] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ScheduledDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [OverdueDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Sent] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SendTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [SendSuccess] [bit] NULL
)



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAttachments](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    EmailId [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES tblEmails(Id),
    [FilePath] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [FileName] [nvarchar](200) NULL
)

GO

CREATE VIEW vwPendingAttachments AS
    SELECT a.*
    FROM tblAttachments a
    INNER JOIN tblEmails e
    ON a.EmailId = e.Id
    WHERE e.Active = 1 AND e.Sent != 1

GO

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Messages:

Msg 1763, Level 16, State 0, Line 23

Cross-database foreign key references are not supported. Foreign key 'Foo_Apps.dbo.tblApps'.

Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 23

Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwPendingAttachments, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 59]

Invalid object name 'tblAttachments'.

Msg 3903, Level 16, State 1, Line 70

The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Comment: Typically you would check that `@@TRANCOUNT ` is greater than 0 before rolling back in case a nested statement has already performed a rollback i.e. in a trigger or so. Seems to me you're doing it wrong if you are regularly modifying your table structure in code?

Comment: _I believe that the UPDATE commands also errored because it didn't recognize ClientId as a valid column._ That may have been a syntax error from SSMS itself (rather than SQL Server) if you submitted the entire query posted in the question as a single execute request.

Comment: Maybe you had network issues and the connection was dropped at some point, rolling back the work done until that point. When SSMS reconnected, there was no open transaction.

Comment: @RazvanSocol, the physical server _is_ at another location, but runtime was shorter than what I'd expect any timeout to be, I noticed no other connection issues that day (all files I use are stored on a server at the same physical location), and I was able to recreate the behavior of the rollback erroring.

However... I did some additional testing today and I have not been able to recreate the error... the rollback is behaving as expected, and the UPDATE command is no longer erroring.

Comment: Can you find something in sp_readerrorlog at that time?

Comment: @RazvanSocol, I don't believe so. There are various "Setting database option" items that I believe were added when the database (and two others) was created, then nothing that could be attributed to this issue.